# MySQL time/date calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, time

First, an entry in the database:

[image]

I have an input form that writes start date, start and end times (in hour and minute) of working days plus lunch break in minutes (in the example dato=date, modetime=start hour, modeminut=start minute, fyrtime=end hour, fyrminut=end minute). I need to do several calculations:

- First calculate the date, start hour and minute into the datetime field modetid.
- The do a similar calculation with the end hours and minutes, but move the date up one day if end hours is less than start hour (lets call it fyrtid)
- And finally calculate the difference between fyrtid and modetid minus the pause minutes.

Can it be done directly and automatically in the database (if yes, how) or do I need some PHP to do it (and again, if yes, how)?

I know its a tall order but I have not been able to find much information on date/time calculations that made much sense on my low level of knowledge. Any link to a comprehensive guide on date/time calculation in MySQL or PHP would also be greatly welcomed.

Comment: what version of phpmyadmin are you using? it's nicer than mine

Comment: I would suggest using datetime instead of date in MySQL.  This will allow you to store all the data in one field and make your calculations much easier, since PHP and MySQL have numerous ways to calculate and differences, add, subtract, etc against full datetimes.

Comment: Agree with Mikecito mysql has datetime fields for a reason. storing minutes and hours and stuff separately makes it so that you cannot use MySQL datetime functions, as well as makes PHP side calcualtions more complicated.

Comment: yes123:3.4.0       BTW: can anyone actually SEE anything in the picture. I appreciate whoever put the picture in the post but I am not sure its better than the linked full scale version: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1624676/mysql.png

Comment: Okay, inching my way ahead. If I want my users to have separate hour and minute input fields can I somehow combine the fields when I save to the database? FOr example, can I modify the dato field (and how), so it includes the hours and minutes: mysql_real_escape_string(YDFLValue($_SESSION['form']['item_10'])) . "', dato = '"  (start hour is item_2, start minute is item_3)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to work by php function time() it's based on unix timestamp ( like UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in Mysql ) unix time is like this : 1307387678.
Use a calender in your form for start time also for your end time.
put a facility what clients could select time of day ( hour and minutes ) then covert those fileds by strtotime() to unix timestamp like following code ( set date format to mm/dd/yyyy  ) :

```
$startdate = strtotime ( "$_POST['calender_start'] $_POST['hour_start']:$_POST['minutes_start']"  );
$enddate = strtotime ( "$_POST['calender_end'] $_POST['hour_end']:$_POST['minutes_end']"  );
```

Change your db table fields to : cpr,startDate,endDate,pause,basked,.....

it's so flexible.
while you want to fetch special recorde you could fetch rows by this sql :

```
SELECT ...... FROM [TABLE_NAME] WHERE [VALUE] BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

I hope it be usefull for you

Comment: It looks like it should be the way to go, if I understand it correctly. But as I said, I know next to nothing about PHP and MySQL. I am trying to hack an automatic form builder i Rapidweaver so I am probably getting the syntax all wrong everywhere.

Comment: ...and putting things in the wrong places. Here is my hack: http://www.konferencer.nu/example.txt